# How to access cell properties in below case device tree

Tags: c, linux, device-tree

I have a device tree node like this

```
gpio_dummy: gpio-dummy {
    gpio-phandles = <&gpio0 &gpio1 &gpio2 &gpio3 &gpio4 &gpio5 &gpio6 &gpio7>;
};
```

which becomes this

```
gpio-dummy {
            gpio-phandles = <0xd6 0x153 0x154 0x159 0x14c 0x115 0x15a 0x15b>;
};
```

And I want to get each phandle in gpio-phandles
I tried this,

```
struct device_node *parent = NULL;
const u32 *reg=NULL;
parent = of_find_node_by_path("/gpio-dummy");
if (!parent)
    printk("%s: no parent\n",__func__);
else{
    reg = of_get_property(parent, "gpio-phandles", NULL);
    for (i=0; i < 7 ;i++){          
        printk(" value : %x ", *(reg+i) );
    }
}
```

But except first value I don't get other values right?

How to get other values?

Comment: What is `"gpio-dummy-refs"`? Did you mean `"gpio-phandles"`?

Comment: Yes gpio-dummy-refs is a property to keep reference of all gpio phandles.

Comment: You can call `of_property_read_u32_index` to read u32 values from the array property if you need the actual phandle values for some reason, or use the `of_property_for_each_u32` iterator. If your intention is to access the device nodes referenced by the phandles, you would be better off using `of_parse_phandle` (which takes an array index) or the `of_for_each_phandle` iterator.